# Telegram Bot API with Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, google-sheets-api

Do you know if it is possible to send an answer from Google Sheets to Telegram?

For example if somebody made a request, I would answer him from a Google Sheets table directly, writing a message in the table cell.

My bot wrote on the JavaScript, maybe this function may do that:

```
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there");
}

function doPost(e) {
  // this is where telegram works
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;
  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Hi, " + name + " wait an answer  " + text;
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);
```

Comment: what do you mean by *answer him from google sheet table directly*?

Comment: I mean that I would write a message in googlesheet and it would sent to user in telegram. Sent from google sheet.

Comment: it wont do automatically , only if I write a message in google sheet and user will get my message in telegram

Comment: I think you should add more detailed explanation how should it work to your question

Comment: I just want to write in google sheet in cell.  And that message will be sent to telegram bot

Comment: can you send an HTTP request using google sheets API?

Comment: according to official API page, you cannot do that

Comment: thanks , will try !